# Compiling Java into application in VSCode on Mac

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar

I'm new to Java, and new to how Java's compiling stuff works with its Virtual Machine, so please write your answer in simple terms.

I am using VSCode (on macOS) to make a Java application. I am using `Eclipse New Java Project` to create my projects, which sets up a file structure like so:

```
TestApp
│
│-- .vscode
│-- bin
╵-- src
  ╵-- app
    ╵-- App.java
```

Now I am able to compile my simple project, and it prints within vscode:

```
package app;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

How do I now go about running it similar to an application? I have had a long look around, and found things about creating a `.jar` file, but I don't get what this is doing.

Is the `.jar` an executable? When I try click on it I get an error, and after searching that up, I saw that you need to add the main class somehow, and I keep getting lots of errors and nothing is working from the many solutions on Stack Overflow.

In simple terms, how do I compile a Java project so I can open it like an app instead of compiling within vscode every time? Is there an option within vscode which makes this `.jar` and stuff for me?

Comment: Assuming that you can run the javac command, something like: javac -cp ./src app.App should work. There are a few other posts that specify how you can compile to a jar when you have to deal with packages.

Comment: @LethalLadders I can run the `javac` command, but which directory should I use? `.../TestApp/bin/app`?

Comment: For the command I stated, you should be in the /TestApp I believe. The -cp specifies the rest of the path (in this case the src folder). And then app.App says compile the App class in the app package .

Comment: @LethalLadders After getting `Class names, 'app.App', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested` I tried putting `.java` on the end, which still doesn't work (`file not found: app.App.java`)

Comment: @LethalLadders Also, doesn't `javac` just produce a class? I already have `App.class` produced by vscode in `bin`.

Comment: Sorry its been a while (and thought there was a different way). Once you have the class files, it seems that you'd need to run a command like: jar MyApp.jar app.App.class

Comment: @LethalLadders That command doesn't work :(

Comment: Is it recognized?

Comment: @LethalLadders Replacing `MyApp` with the actual name, I get "`Illegal option: T`" when in `bin` (tried others, couldn't find a working directory)

Comment: try adding cf after jar. As in jar cf MyApp.jar app.App.Class or wherever the files are

Comment: Now I am getting `app.App.class : no such file or directory`? Why is this so awkward :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200968/discussion-between-lethalladders-and-george-e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running in the terminal (and specifying where the main method is):

```
jar -cvfe Test.jar App ./app
java -cp Test.jar app/App
```

For including the entry point (so that you can click on the .jar file to run it):

```
jar -cvfe Test.jar app.App ./App
jar cfe Test.jar app.App *
```

Comment: And run in `bin` directory ^